# GLSurfaceView sizing and black bars

Tags: android, android-layout, android-bitmap, glsurfaceview

i'm doing app for applying filters to image. I got rendering code from android samples, but i have some problems with GLSurfaceView saving or converting into Bitmap.

Here is code for saving into Bitmap

```
private Bitmap createBitmapFromGLSurface(int x, int y, int w, int h, GL10 gl)
            throws OutOfMemoryError {

        int bitmapBuffer[] = new int[w * h];
        int bitmapSource[] = new int[w * h];
        IntBuffer intBuffer = IntBuffer.wrap(bitmapBuffer);
        intBuffer.position(0);
        try {
            gl.glReadPixels(0, 0, imageView.getWidth(), imageView.getHeight(), GL10.GL_RGBA, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, intBuffer);
            int offset1, offset2;
            for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
                offset1 = i * w;
                offset2 = (h - i - 1) * w;
                for (int j = 0; j < w; j++) {
                    int texturePixel = bitmapBuffer[offset1 + j];
                    int blue = (texturePixel >> 16) & 0xff;
                    int red = (texturePixel << 16) & 0x00ff0000;
                    int pixel = (texturePixel & 0xff00ff00) | red | blue;
                    bitmapSource[offset2 + j] = pixel;
                }
            }
        } catch (GLException e) {
            return null;
        }

        return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapSource, w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    }
```

Here you can see an example (black bars above and below is redundant
[image: Here you can see an example (black bars above and below is redundant]

I tried to change GlSurfaceView size and with that get rid of black bars, but it just going "match_parent" all time. (I'm taking ready ImageView params for width and height)

```
 ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams=mEffectView.getLayoutParams();
 layoutParams.width=mImageViewWidth;
 layoutParams.height=mImageViewHeight;
 mEffectView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Also I tried to add some offset when creating Bitmap, but it all did nothing, or broke image.
What can I do to get rid of black bars? (They also can be from sides)
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just before calling this method:

```
createBitmapFromGLSurface(0, 0, mEffectView.getWidth(), mEffectView.getHeight(), gl);
```

What you can do is just set `Height` & `Width` of `GLSurfaceView` to `Height` & `Width` of `bitmap` like this.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mEffectView.getLayoutParams().height = bitmapOriginal.getHeight();
        mEffectView.getLayoutParams().width = bitmapOriginal.getWidth();
        mEffectView.requestLayout();
    }
});
```

> So the code will be like :

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mEffectView.getLayoutParams().height = bitmapOriginal.getHeight();
        mEffectView.getLayoutParams().width = bitmapOriginal.getWidth();
        mEffectView.requestLayout();
    }
});

createBitmapFromGLSurface(0, 0, mEffectView.getWidth(), mEffectView.getHeight(), gl);
```

> ## Update:

In your XML make sure to set `GLSurfaceView` to `wrap_content` both `height` & `width`

Hope this solves the problem